# ArcFM Session Manager is showing error while OPEN EDIT SESSION

Tags: arcfm

I am configuring session manager from scratch. I followed below link and executed the steps.
http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/10.1/EngineConfig/SMOracle.html

I configured process framework administrator also. Screen shot attached.

I am using SDE user. when I try to Open edit session after creation I am getting error and not able to open the session:

This session's version could not be found.  You may not be connected to the

database, the version referenced by this session may have been deleted, or

the version's permission may have been changed to private.

[image]

I checked with below things:

1. SDE has all the permission on the mm tables
2. Compressed the database and checked state is 0 for the version

Not sure what is wrong with database . Please suggest

Comment: Which version of oracle client are you using? We had to edit the registry to get session manager to see the oracle database, also does someone else there have an already session manager?

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production. No one else having session manager.. it's a non ArcFM geodatabase. I am doing fresh configuration. I executed the steps which is requires for session manager.

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production. No one else having session manager.. it's a non ArcFM geodatabase. I am doing fresh configuration. I executed the steps which  is requires for session manager.   Not aware about the registry edit. Please let me know what need to be done  @Banger

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you have to run the 32 bit client for ArcFM and ArcMap. We are running the 32bit 11g edition and then I have the 64bit 12.1 client for ArcGIS Pro.

The easiest thing to try first might be just install the 32 bit 12.1 client and see if that works.  Ideally you install the 32bit client first and then the 64 bit client but it might work the other way around. It may just be easier to run the 32 bit client if you don't require the 64 bit one for ArcGIS Pro or other software.

You may also need to swap the environment variables around in the system path so it sees the path for the 64 bit home first.

If that doesn't work, these are the instructions we have at work which is apparently a work around for a bug with the 11.x editions of the oracle client. Also this is what I had to do on my machine which was setup by someone else previously and I had ArcGiS Pro and oracle instant client 12 64 bit installed before I put ArcFM on my machine so I had to fiddle around with it alot.

Firstly check if Client_admin & client-Developer are installed.

Go to C\Program Files(x86)\Oracle\Inventory\ContentsXML\inventory.xml
Open the XML document
You should see a line of text

Or

In your situation it will be \12.x

**For machines with the Admin Client:**
Test for files
Open a cmd window with admin privileges
Windows key + R  type cmd then ctl shift + enter

Type: dir c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_admin\BIN\OraOLEDB11.DLL

This checks if the file is present

If the above dir command works then type the following to edit the registry

Regsvr32.exe c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_admin\BIN\OraOLEDB11.DLL
Regsvr32.exe c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_admin\BIN\oip11.dll

**For a machine with the developer client:**
Test for files
Open cmd window with admin privilages
Windows key + R  type cmd then ctl shift + enter

Type: dir c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_developer\BIN\OraOLEDB11.DLL

If the above dir command works then run the following to edit the registry

Regsvr32.exe c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_ developer \BIN\OraOLEDB11.DLL
Regsvr32.exe c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_ developer \BIN\oip11.dll

For a machine with a manual install
Test for files
Open cmd window with admin privilages

Windows key + R  type cmd then ctl shift + enter

Type dir c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN\OraOLEDB11.DLL

If the above dir command works then run the following to edit the registry
Regsvr32.exe c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_ 1 \BIN\OraOLEDB11.DLL
Regsvr32.exe c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_ 1 \BIN\oip11.dll

Because my computer was having problems switching between the 64bit and 32 bit homes, I also followed the instructions found here

http://realfiction.net/2009/11/26/Use-32-and-64bit-Oracle-Client-in-parallel-on-Windows-7-64-bit-for-eg-NET-Apps/

Also check that the tnsnames.ora file which is found C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_admin\network\admin points to the database, mine was empty so I copied an existing tnsnames.ora file from a working computer.